Combining mean and covariance matrix of two populations
Say I have a population $X$ of points $x_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ broken into two subgroups $X_1$ and $X_2$ of sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ respectively.
If I know the means $\mu_1, \mu_2$ and covariance matrices $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ of the two subgroups, how do I compute the mean and covariance of the total population $X$?
I have encountered the formula for pooled covariance $$\frac{(n_1 - 1)\Sigma_1 + (n_2 - 1)\Sigma_2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}$$
but I understand this relies on the assumption that the two populations have the same mean and covariance, which I do not think it is safe for me to assume. For one, this does not seem to account for the change to the covariance I would expect to see if the two sub-populations are widely separated.
I need the mean and covariance of the combined group $X$ exactly as if I had computed it from the total population of individual elements $x_i$. What is this formula? (I'm finding it unexpectedly hard to find the formula I need). And does the formula change if $n_1$ and $n_2$ are instead taken to be real-valued weights (I assume not)?

You need a decomposition of the pooled covariance matrix
The formula you have given in your question is for the simple case where the samples have the same sample mean.  That is not particularly useful in practice since samples don't behave this nicely.  The more general formula requires a bit of vector algebra to derive, but it still has a fairly simple form.
To show you how to do this, I'm going to generalise your analysis to the case where we have $k$ samples of data vectors.  Let me begin by setting up notation for the samples and pooled sample in the problem.  Let $\mathbf{x}_i$ be an $N \times n_i$ matrix representing a sample of $n_i$ data vectors with length $N$ (each column of the matrix is one data vector in the sample).  We will denote the sample mean and sample covariance of this data by $\bar{\mathbf{x}}_i$ and $\mathbf{s}_i^2$ respectively.  Let $\mathbf{x}_\bullet \equiv [\mathbf{x}_1 \ \cdots \ \mathbf{x}_k]$ denote the pooled sample composed of $k$ samples with respective sample sizes $n_1,...,n_k$.  The pooled sample is an $N \times n_\bullet$ matrix where $n_\bullet \equiv n_1 + \cdots + n_k$ is the pooled sample size.
Now, with a bit of vector algebra, one can obtain the following decompositions for the pooled sample mean and pooled sample covariance:
$$\begin{align}
\bar{\mathbf{x}}_\bullet
&= \frac{1}{n_\bullet} \sum_i n_i \bar{\mathbf{x}}_i, \\[12pt]
\mathbf{s}_\bullet^2
&= \frac{1}{n_\bullet-1} \Bigg[ \sum_i (n_i-1) \mathbf{s}_i^2 + \sum_i n_i \cdot \bar{\mathbf{x}}_i \bar{\mathbf{x}}_i^\text{T} - \sum_i \sum_j \frac{n_i n_j}{n_\bullet} \cdot \bar{\mathbf{x}}_i \bar{\mathbf{x}}_j^\text{T} \Bigg]. \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$
If you prefer, you can also write the pooled covariance matrix with the aid of the pooled mean vector using the formula:
$$\mathbf{s}_\bullet^2
= \frac{1}{n_\bullet-1} \Bigg[ \sum_i (n_i-1) \mathbf{s}_i^2 + \sum_i n_i \cdot \bar{\mathbf{x}}_i \bar{\mathbf{x}}_i^\text{T} - n_\bullet \cdot \bar{\mathbf{x}}_\bullet \bar{\mathbf{x}}_\bullet^\text{T} \Bigg].
\quad \quad \quad \quad \ \ \ $$
These decompositions allow you to compute the pooled sample mean and the pooled sample covarince using the sample sizes, sample means and sample covariances of the underlying samples.  The general formula does not assume that the samples have the same mean vector, but in the (pathologically unusual) special case where the samples all have the same mean $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$, you get the simplified formula $\mathbf{s}_\bullet^2 = \sum_i (n_i-1) \mathbf{s}_i^2/ (n_\bullet-1)$.

Your problem: The case you are interested in uses $k=2$ samples, so the relevant decompositions reduce to:
$$\begin{align}
\bar{\mathbf{x}}_\bullet
&= \frac{1}{n_1+n_2} \Bigg[ n_1 \bar{\mathbf{x}}_1 + n_2 \bar{\mathbf{x}}_2 \Bigg], \\[12pt]
\mathbf{s}_\bullet^2
&= \frac{1}{n_1+n_2-1} \Bigg[ (n_1-1) \mathbf{s}_1^2 + (n_2-1) \mathbf{s}_2^2 + \frac{n_1 n_2}{n_1+n_2} (\bar{\mathbf{x}}_1-\bar{\mathbf{x}}_2) (\bar{\mathbf{x}}_1-\bar{\mathbf{x}}_2)^\text{T}\Bigg]. \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$
The latter is the formula you will need to apply to get the pooled covariance from two samples.
